# Is there a built-in way to efficiently search a unique, sorted array in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, search

Does PowerShell have a built-in method for an optimized search for a specific value in a unique, sorted array or collection that returns the index of the found value in the searched collection?  Or perhaps a built-in collection type that provides such a method?

I know it's a fairly simple process to efficiently find a specific value in a sorted array or collection, and I could write a function to do this myself, but I hate reinventing the wheel!  However, my searches have only turned up page upon page describing how to sort unsorted data in PowerShell.

Here is my specific use case:  I have a set of SQL query results in PowerShell object form that, because of the way the SQL script was written, I *know* is unique and sorted.  I have another set of data, and I need to find matching values from that other set within the SQL results.  I want to do this efficiently rather than just iteratively looping until a match is found, but I don't want to write custom logic for such a common task when there almost certainly has to be something already available in PowerShell for doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the data type, both, [`Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-7.0) and [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) have their own `BinarySearch` method, optimized for searching in sorted collections. This method has a time complexity of **O(log `n`)**.

```bash
$array = 50..100
[array]::BinarySearch($array, 75) # Index: 25

[System.Collections.Generic.List[int]] $list = 50..100
$list.BinarySearch(75) # Index: 25
```

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=net-7.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-7.0

---

Bonus for anyone curious how these methods perform against a linear search algorithm **O(`n`)** time complexity such as `IndexOf` (tests available in [my gists](https://gist.github.com/santisq/1dd35ba142ea6dc7ebd9f26184ddd13b#file-binarysearch-perf-ps1)).

Results from the tests show the following average milliseconds to find the index of a value in collections with 10.485.761 items:

```bash
Test               Average RelativeSpeed
----               ------- -------------
List.BinarySearch     0.09 1x
Array.BinarySearch    0.15 1.67x
Array.IndexOf         3.63 40.33x
List.IndexOf          5.03 55.89x
```

Comment: Thank you!  "Binary search" is clearly the terminology I was looking for, I had just forgotten what it was called.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that's independent of indexing and has lookup complexitiy O(1) is a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.3). There's a [built-in type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.3) for that in Powershell. If your dataset already has an unique key, you can use that as hashtable key and put the data as value. As for a bonus, a hashtable doesn't need sorted data for input.

As an example, consider made-up dataset like so,

```
# This would be your colums from SQL query
$dataset = @("1,a,b", "2,c,d", "3,e,f", "4,g,h", "10,aa,bb")
$ht = @{}

foreach($d in $dataset) {
    # Get unique id from 1st column for ht key
    $key = ($d -split ',')[0]
    # Add the whole row as data for the key
    $ht.Add($key, $d)
}
```

The first column is used as hashtable key. One can now access the hashtable by using the key with brackets, but mind that the index is not numeric but by string. Like so,

```
$ht['10']
10,aa,bb
```

Looking up data [by key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.containskey?view=net-7.0#system-collections-hashtable-containskey(system-object)) is O(1), but looking up [by value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.containsvalue?view=net-7.0#system-collections-hashtable-containsvalue(system-object)) is possible too. That's O(n) since it's a linear search.

```
$ht.ContainsKey('2')
True
$ht.ContainsValue('2,c,d')
True
```

Comment: Thank you for the response – this is a good thought, but I would like to avoid the overhead of rebuilding the entire dataset into a hashtable.  Since the source data is already unique and sorted, I'm not sure that overhead is worth it when it can already be searched with O(log n) efficiency.